# Are these statements correct for all reductive groups, or just for $\operatorname{GL}_2$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups

I'm reading the following [notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/JLseminar/Notes/L2.pdf) on Brian Conrad's website.  There are a couple of statements there which seem too good to be true.  There is Proposition 3.6, which states:

> (Bernstein): Every irreducible smooth representation of $\mathbf G(F)$ is admissible.

where $\mathbf G$ is a connected, reductive group over a $p$-adic local field $F$, and Theorem 5.3:

> Let $\pi$ be an irreducible admissible smooth representation of a td-group $H$ with center $Z$.  If some nonzero matrix coefficient of $\pi$ has support that is compact modulo $Z$, then all matrix coefficients of $\pi$ have the same property and $\pi$ is admissible.

I believe in this last statement the first sentence should read "Let $\pi$ be an irreducible smooth representation..."

I am skeptical because the citation for Theorem 5.3 is Henniart and Bushnell's book on the Local Langlands Conjecture for $\operatorname{GL}_2$, which only proves the given proposition in the case $H = \operatorname{GL}_2(F)$.  And the notes claim that Bernstein's theorem makes use  of this last result.

Comment: I don't know about the second statement but the first statement is true. Some sources attribute it to Bernstein and some to Jacquet, in the paper "Sur les representations des groupes reductifs p-adiques." The reductive condition is necessary.

Comment: David Renard's book (published a few years ago) treats these issues for general reductive groups. I remember corresponding with him about filling in details for J. Bernstein's proof of admissibility for supercuspidal irrreducibles, for example, which was very sketchy in the original. Certainly Jacquet's Montecatini Lectures (c. 1971) already touch on these things, though the admissibility of irred supercuspidals seems not to have been known till the mid-1970s.

Comment: The typo with "admissible" for the statement of Theorem 5.3 has been fixed. Remark 1 after Prop. 10.1 in Ch. 3 of the Bushnell-Henniart book addresses the general context for the proof they give (the unimodularity condition B-H mentions there, which is only needed modulo the center and of course holds in the context of connected reductive groups, is implicit for the work with Hecke algebras in section 4 of Chapter 3 of that book).